# Bootstrap grid not working properly rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I'm trying to create my portfolio site using rails and bootstrap-sass gem and I cant seem to get the column layouts working.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/thyat/

My style sheet is empty and my haml code is

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %title #{ full_title(yield(:title))}
    = stylesheet_link_tag    :application, :media => "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true
    = javascript_include_tag :application, "data-turbolinks-track" => true
    = csrf_meta_tags
    %meta{ "http-equiv" => "Content-Type", :content => "text/html; charset=utf-8" }
    = render 'layouts/shim'
  %body
    .container
      = render 'layouts/header'    

      = yield    

      = render 'layouts/footer'
```

header layout

```
.row 
  %header
    .col-lg-2.col-md-2.logo-image
      = image_tag  'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mikaimages/star.png', alt: 'Eight fold star'
    .col-lg-4.col-md-4.logo-text
      %p Mika
      %p Kalathil    

    %nav.col-lg-6.col-md-6
```

Edit after searching the fiddle it seems that no columns in css have been set by bootstrap. Anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your fiddle, your HTML is coded based on Bootstrap 3. 
(Referring to col-md-2 etc)

However, your CSS seems to be based on bootstrap 2.3.1. The syntax is different. Bootstrap 2.3.1 uses span2 instead.

You probably might want to refer to Bootstrap-sass gem to install bootstrap 3.